# Fatal error #324 NOT 316 or 317! : Call to undefined function apply_filters() in /home/wilwin/public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 324

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I have made some updates to my version of wordpress plugins and php version 5.6, which was working well yesterday. As of today they are not working when I reverted to a backup version. Can someone tell me what I can do to remedy?

Tried to change the php back to 5.2, which was the previous version, but it is no longer an option

Comment: Screenshot ot the error

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-apply_filters-in-homeu126897984publ/ - https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/3308 - https://github.com/johnpbloch/wordpress/issues/22